# ListView vs SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Well, I am making a chat application I am confused about which component should I opt for rendering chats, between `SingleChildScrollView` and `ListView`, I read a couple of articles, and they suggest

> `SingleChildScrollView`, Since it's a chat application so each chat
> bubble will not be the same therefore `ListView` will not be performant.

But, In `SingleChildScrollView` all items inside the column are rendered at once even if they are not inside the `ViewPort` or in other words visible. Doing so should not be memory efficient.

So which one should I Opt?

Answer (score 2):

You should go for the `ListView.builder()` since it creates items on demand.

Example:

```dart
child: ListView.builder(
  reverse: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35, bottom: 25),
  itemCount: messages.length,
  controller: controller,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ChatBubble(
      time: messages[index].time,
      chatPartner: chatPartner,
      message: messages[index].message,
      isMe: messages[index].sentBy != cId ? true : false,
    );
  },
),
```

docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html